# Docker image share the OS system file and configuration?

Tags: docker

Consider I have below Dockerfile from ubuntu old version say 14.0.4

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY ./ /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

What i understand from recent docker learning is docker keeps all required file in image which we can run as container anywhere irrespective
of environment .

My question is will this image also contain OS(Ubuntu 14.0.4) specific file/libs (except kernel)? Now if I run this image on Ubuntu 16.0.4, 
will it run with 14.0.4 OS with 16.0.4 kernel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker image contains all filesystem related files, you can treat it as a system without kernel.

From your dockerfile, your image is based on `php:7.2-apache`, so for your situation:

- You run container on one 14.0.4 host machine:

  It use the files of `php:7.2-apache`, shares the kernel of your host machine, that is 14.0.4's kernel.
- You run container on one 16.0.4 host machine:

  It use the files of `php:7.2-apache`, shares the kernel of your host machine, that is 16.0.4's kernel.

**To sum up:**

Docker container just share host kernel, never share files of your host machine.

For your scenario, `php:7.2-apache` dockerfile is [here](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/d97098c8c6af46ae1211e65ff052278ab39ba45c/7.2/stretch/apache/Dockerfile), so it just use the bins and libs of `debian:stretch-slim`.

And next picture may make you understand clear. In this picture, you can see `ubuntu:15.04` was inside the block of `Image layers`, so after a image was built out, what the system the container will be used has been fixed, `Container layer` just share the kernel from `host machine`.

[image]